# Definition of Cis-eqtl

Tags: gene, snp

I have simple question, do cis-eQTLs use the SNPs that are within 1 Mb from the gene's TSS on the same chromosome ?

Answer (score 1):

Kind of.

What you describe is a cis-eQTL, but the exact distance (1Mb in each direction, 1Mb total, ...) and the definition of the location of the gene (TSS, transcript borders, ...) depend on whoever calculates a cis-eQTLs and are not universal.
The 'cis' part just means the SNP is somehow near the gene, there is no defined limit on the distance.